# Executing code in if-statement (Bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement

## New question:

I can't do this (Error: `line 2: [: ==: unary operator expected`):

```
if [ $(echo "") == "" ]
then
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

But this works fine:

```
tmp=$(echo "")
if [ "$tmp" == "" ]
then
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

Why?

## Original question:

Is it possible to get the result of a command inside an if-statement?

I want to do something like this:

```
if [ $(echo "foo") == "foo" ]
then
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

I currently use this work-around:

```
tmp=$(echo "foo")
if [ "$tmp" == "foo" ]
then
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

Comment: This: `if [ $(echo "foo") == "foo" ];
then
    echo "Success!";
fi`

Comment: Oh sorry, the real problem is that i can't do this: `if [ $(echo "") == "" ]; then echo "Success!"; fi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **yes** -- You can evaluate a command inside an `if` condition. The only thing I would change in your first example is the quoting:

```
if [ "$(echo foo)" == "foo" ]
then 
    echo "Success"'!'
fi
```

- Note the funny quote for the `'!'`. This disables the special behavior of `!` inside an interactive bash session, that might produce unexpected results for you.

---

After your update your problem becomes clear, and the change in quoting actually solves it:

The evaluation of `$(...)` occurs before the evaluation of `if [...]`, thus if `$(...)` evaluates to an empty string the `[...]` becomes `if [ == ""]` which is illegal syntax.

The way to solve this is having the quotes outside the `$(...)` expression. This is where you might get into the sticky issue of quoting inside quoting, but I will live this issue to another question.

Comment: I've just tested this code, and it still starts new shell. After I exit shell, Success is printed out. Using GNU bash 4.1.5

Comment: What if i need to use a command that requires me to escape a variable inside this? Example `str="123 456 789"; if [ "$(someCommand $str)" == "foo" ]; then echo "Success!"; fi` and someCommand only checks the first param

Comment: :( My bad, I've accidentally started new bash at start of script. Everything works correctly. :D

Comment: @Tyilo, quoting with double quotes allows for evaluation of `$str` so your example should work, but preserving spaces might be a thornier issue: E.g. if `str="123  456 789"` (note the 2 spaces between "123" and "456"), in that case you might want to try `"$(someCommand "$str")"`.